# How do I hide the Battle Log?

Tags: card-hunter

The battle log occupies a fair amount of real estate in the top left corner of my screen, even in full screen mode. On a laptop or a tablet, it's taking away a decent chunk of my battle field.

Is there a way to turn this log off or hide it?

Answer (score 1):

The top left corner of the screen? Maybe it's chat you're talking about? If so, then there is a way to hide it. "H" key switches between three modes (always visible, auto and always hidden) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The battlelog is the same space as the chat window, yeah. You can switch between chat and log.

Comment: Pressing the H key doesn't do anything when I'm on the battle screen.